# CSS Not Selector Not Selecting Single Page

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML Code on page 1

```
<body class="page-template-default page page-id-23">
<header class="nav_header">

</header>
</body>
```

And the following HTML Code on page 2

```
<body class="page-template-default page page-id-22">
<header class="nav_header">

</header>
</body>
```

And the following CSS

```
header.nav_header:not(.page-id-23) {
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0)!important;
}
```

I am trying to place the background color on every page except the one with page-id-23 in the body class however have not had success with my current CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a css class selector on the `nav_header` element (where it isn't), instead of the `body` element (where it is). You want this:

```
body:not(.page-id-23) header.nav_header {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0)!important;
}
```